# How to save state of execution in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have an assignment in python for which some complicated idea is needed.
please help me . . . . . 
suppose initially i have a file to load into an array 'arr01' then i have two python source code file say 'a.py' and 'b.py'.

a.py takes some element from that loaded array 'arr01' and modifies the array 'arr01' and send an argument to b.py.

b.py will generate a string 'str' and whenever nedded further data it wil call a.py to send more elements.

the problem here is that the array arr01 should to loaded and the execution state of a.py and b.py must be saved because b.py will call a.py whenever element is needed and a.py must have to keep the track of elements that it has sent to b.py from arr01

how can i use both a.py and b.py simutaniously?

Comment: you import one module in the other.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should get you there:

- define in `a.py` a class with a method that provides data from arr01 and tracks what has been sent
- `import a` in `b.py`
- call the class method from `a` in your code in `b`

Comment: it is very simple. i know it too. :-( but problem is that when even b.py is called it will regenerate the same array arr01. but cant get the last update where it was left

Comment: If you need a persistent record (works when you close python and start again) then consider writing to another file that keeps a record of where you are in arr01

Answer (score 0):

`from a import function_name`

`from b import other_function_name`

From here, you can use a.py and b.py functions in this python file.

E.g.

## a.py

`def say_hi():
    print 'hello'`

## b.py

`from a import say_hi
say_hi()`